# oAuth2Client how do you pass the token on to the library

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth2client

I guess I'm just missing something here.

I'm trying to setup https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client with my App.

I don't understand how I have to pass the oauth token to the library.

I call:

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] requestAccessToAccountWithType:@"myFancyService"];
```

I then successfully get a token in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
```

How do I pass the token on to the library?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out one has to call:

```
 [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] handleRedirectURL:url];
```

in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use NXOAuth2Request to use your OAuthToken to invoke a request.  The example code from their github page is below. The Token is wrapped by the NXOAuth2Account class which is in turn wrapped in the NXOAuth2AccountStore singleton.

```
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accounts]
```

Will return an array of accounts.

You can then use your account as a parameter in the following method to make your authenticated API calls.

```
[NXOAuth2Request performMethod:@"GET"
                onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://...your service URL..."]
           usingParameters:nil
               withAccount:anAccount
       sendProgressHandler:^(unsigned long long bytesSend, unsigned long long bytesTotal) { // e.g., update a progress indicator }
           responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){
               // Process the response
           }];
```

Comment: I checked [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accounts]. But the account isn't created at this point. It first needs to be initialised with an AccessToken. I've the access token but I don't now how to pass it to on to the library so that an account gets created :(

Comment: I've the token as an NSString. My problem is that I don't know how to create the account from the token as the init methods of NXOAuthAccount are private.